# Как проверить код ответа страницы (404, 200 и т.д.)?

Tags: python, requests, браузер, webbrowser

Нужно проверить сайт на работоспособность (или на ошибки, по типу **404**) и если сайт рабочий и без ошибок, то его надо открыть с помощью модуля webbrowser. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали, в чём у вас **конкретная** проблема или проблемы?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как это реализовать? Пытаюсь через парсинг, но так как я новичок в этом, возможны глупые проблемы

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. Вам надо проверить `html` файл? Или вам надо проверить сайт, который отдаётся сервером? Что у вас есть на входе? Сайт просто через `requests` открываете да смотрите `status_code` ответа, там будет 200 или 404 или что-то ещё.

Comment: Например, возмём Хабр (https://habr.com/ru/post/470938500/). Как у него найти этот status_code? Или у него что-то другое?

Comment: статус-код не "у него", статус-код это часть ответа сервера.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот простейшая проверка через `requests`:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://habr.com/ru/post/470938500/')
print(r.status_code)
r = requests.get('https://habr.com')
print(r.status_code)
```

Вывод:

```
404
200
```

Хотя 404 не означает не работоспособность сайта. Сайт может и работать, просто конкретная страница на нём не найдена. Что и есть в данном случае - запрос к корню сайта вполне успешно проходит.

Comment: Я тут заметил, что, например, у YouTube такой способ не пройдёт, он выдаёт 200 даже если видео не найдено. Как быть в таких случаях?

Comment: Для ютьюба есть специальные библиотеки чтобы с ним оптимально общаться. Названия не помню, надо смотреть

Comment: Ну а если взять например imgur (https://imgur.com/gallery/ASADg5), то тут тоже самое, код 200 но содержимого нет, как быть?

Comment: Ну вот поэтому "работоспособность сайта" - это не такой простой вопрос. А если сайт работает, но вместо информации, которую он должен выдавать, выдаёт пустую страницу или требование денег ему заслать или ещё что-то не то - считать что сайт работает или нет? Вы слишком широко ставите вопрос. Если вам нужно прямо определить, что "нужный клип есть на данной странице ютьюба", то это через специальную библиотеку, простым статусом сервиса не обойтись. И так придётся с каждым сайтом индивидуально решать вопрос.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо